# how node js project to make to production

Tags: node.js, deployment, packaging

I want to prepare a project for production and installation on the client's system.
In such a way that I can install all the dependencies on the client's system, make the database connection settings, and then it will be executed, and there is no need for my source codes there.

I want to prepare a project for production and installation on the client's system.
In such a way that I can install all the dependencies on the client's system, make the database connection settings, and then it will be executed, and there is no need for my source codes there